# How can I get the minimum required password length value from Active Directory in .NET

Tags: .net, active-directory, membership-provider

I'm implementing a plugin architecture to implement authentication an external authentication mechanism for a web site.  One of the plugins I plan to provide is an ActiveDirectory plugin.  I'd like to implement some of the features of a MembershipProvider, including MinRequiredPasswordLength, but don't want to fully implement or configure an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.

Does anyone know how to query AD and get the minimum required password length?  I know that this can be set by GPO and vary by user/computer depending on policies, but I'd like to provide a default based on the domain default instead of an arbitrary number.

[EDIT] The configuration [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.minrequiredpasswordlength.aspx) for an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider shows this as being set in the configuration.  Is there no way to have this tied to the domain policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the domain has a property called "minPwdLength"  There are several other attributes related to password policy (minPwdAge, maxPwdAge, lockoutDuration, etc)

In a Windows Server 2008 Domain with Fine Grained Password policy this get's more complicated though since you can have different password policies for different OU's.

Answer (score 0):

just a hint: I use DirectorySearcher (System.DirectoryServices) to query the ActiveDirectory, I don't kbow if there is a way to query what you're looking for...

Hope it helps

Comment: here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of the DirectorySearcher although I'll be using the newer PrincipalContext in the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace for credential validation.  I'm just not sure if there is an object I can find and query for this property.